# How to use actionSubmitImage tag with asset pipeline plugin in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Tags/actionSubmitImage.html) for `actionSubmitImage` tag uses *resource* plugin. How could it be changed to use *asset-pipeline* plugin.

For example:

```
<g:actionSubmitImage action="unassign" value="${message(code: 'default.button.unassign.label', default: 'Unassign')}" 
   onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.unassign.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure to unassign the schema?')}');" 
   title="Remove owner for the current schema" 
   src="${resource(dir: 'skin', file: 'user_delete.png')}" style="display:inline;"/>
```

How does the *src* attribute change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *src* tag `src="${resource(dir: 'skin', file: 'user_delete.png')}"` should be change to `src="${assetPath(src: 'skin/delete.png')}"`. `assetPath` gives the path to the **assets** directory.

```
<g:actionSubmitImage action="drop" value="${message(code: 'default.button.unassign.label', default: 'Drop')}" 
onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.drop.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure to drop the schema?')}');" 
title="Drop schema"
src="${assetPath(src: 'skin/delete.png')}"/>
```